# Does BackboneFire support non-AutoSync collection with AutoSync model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backbone.js-collections, backbonefire

Basically I want this set up:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    },
    autoSync: true
});

var Games = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    url: 'https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com/games',
    autoSync: false,
    model: Game
});
```

Each Game should be auto-synced with server data but I do not not want to listen to the entire child_* Firebase family of events. The goal is to update individual item view instead of repainting the whole list.

Kind regards to folks out there and happy coding ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update individual items by using an `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` with `autoSync` enabled. To do re-render individual items you need to listen to when the items fire the change event. This concept is shown in the BackboneFire Quickstart in the Firebase docs.

A quick note however, you cannot mix a `Backbone.Firebase.Model` with a `Backbone.Firebase.Collection`.

**Todo Model & Collection**

In the below sample, notice how a regular `Backbone.Model` is being used in the `Backbone.Firebase.Collection`. The collection by default has `autoSync` enabled.

```
// A simple todo model
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { title: "New Todo" }
});

// Create a Firebase collection and set the 'firebase' property
// to the URL of your Firebase
var TodoCollection = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo,
  url: "https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

**Todo View**

The below sample is a view for an individual todo item. Inside of the `initialize` function the `listenTo` method is used to listen to a model's `change` event. The `change` event will be fired each time the model is updated either remotely or locally (which persists changes remotely).

```
// A view for an individual todo item
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:  "li",
  template: _.template("<%= title %>"),
  initialize: function() {
    // whenever the model changes trigger a re-render of the single view
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
});
```

**Render List**

With the `TodoView` set up the list can easily be rendered as well. In the `initialize` function of the `AppView` below, we listen to the `collection` which will be a `TodoCollection`. Whenever an item is added to the collection the `addOne` function is executed. The `addOne` function simply appends a new `TodoView` to the page.

```
// The view for the entire application
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#todoapp'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.list = this.$("#todo-list"); // the list to append to

    // by listening to when the collection changes we
    // can add new items in realtime
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
  },
  addOne: function(todo) {
    var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
    this.list.append(view.render().el);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. I set it up wrong at first. My solution is slightly different. First I listen once to the `sync` event, then iterate thru the collection, render the items. For each of the item view I listen to the `change` event as you mentioned. To handle the add and remove I use separate two handlers on the list view and item view, respectively.

So basically the keys are a combination of `sync` once on collection -> `change`, `remove` on each item and `add` on the collection.

Any suggestions?